# How to convert polygons to centriods without losing attribute names?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, centroids

I have a GeoJSON file of polygons and I need to convert it to centroids. Finding the centroid is very easy in QGIS.

**Problem**

My attribute names are very long and have a colon between them, e.g. *building:structure* and *shape:elevation*. Converting to centroids results in a shapefile format. It gives the geometry but changes the attribute names, truncating them and converting colons to underscores, e.g. *building_l* and *shape_elev*.

I need the attribute names in the centroids to be the same as in the original polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [spatial join](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_spatial.php) should solve your problem. Remove any of the problematic columns in your newly created shapefile, then just join all the columns from the containing polygon.

If this doesn't work, you could also consider converting the centroid shapefile to another format that supports your attribute headers before performing the spatial join or creating a lookup table.